# Datepicker issue in Auto Populate input (jQuery/Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am using this [datepicker](https://github.com/chrisdavies/tiny-date-picker/blob/master/docs/tiny-date-picker.md#bundling) in my project. It is not working as usual with jquery auto populating inputs.

This is how my INPUT generate with ajax response, and there are two inputs in the result set.

```
$.post("./item_row_return_data.php",{rowcount: rowcount, item_id:item_id},function(result){
  if (!$("#rowID"+item_id).length) {
    $('#item_offer_table tbody').append(result);
    $("#tableRowCount").val(parseFloat(rowcount)+1);
  }

  calculate(item_id);
  total = 0;
});
```

This is how I call the plugin:

```
  var TinyDatePicker = DateRangePicker.TinyDatePicker;
  TinyDatePicker('.datepicker', {
    mode: 'dp-below',
    format(date) {
      return date.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA");
    },
  })
```

But it doesn't work in this way, So I tried it calling inside ajax response as below. Then its working only for single row. (not for multiple input in multiple rows)

```
$.post("./item_row_return_data.php",{rowcount: rowcount, item_id:item_id},function(result){
  if (!$("#rowID"+item_id).length) {
    $('#item_offer_table tbody').append(result);
    $("#tableRowCount").val(parseFloat(rowcount)+1);
      
    var TinyDatePicker1 = DateRangePicker.TinyDatePicker;
    var TinyDatePicker2 = DateRangePicker.TinyDatePicker;
    TinyDatePicker1('.datepicker1', {
      format(date) {
        return date.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA");
      },
    })            

    TinyDatePicker2('.datepicker2', {
      format(date) {
        return date.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA");
      },
    })
  }

  calculate(item_id);
  total = 0;
});
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through your inputs and then inside this  loop initialize your *TinyDatePicker* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..suppose this is appended to tbody
$('#item_offer_table tbody').append(`<tr><td><input type="text" class="datepicker1"></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker2"></td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" class="datepicker1"></td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker2"></td></tr>`);
//$("#tableRowCount").val(parseFloat(rowcount) + 1);

var TinyDatePicker1 = DateRangePicker.TinyDatePicker;
//iterate through each...elements
$('.datepicker1 ,.datepicker2').each(function() {
  //intialize..them
  TinyDatePicker1($(this)[0], {
    mode: 'dp-below',
    format(date) {
      return date.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA");
    },
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-date-picker/3.2.8/tiny-date-picker.min.css" integrity="sha512-XcVC+nlwCXmH65gjIlz5Lx57HnQlmsL+7fodw4dnbGO0Nto2upjBQuFJGbnzvZrhwBxYY3CwRTRxAlpu+raOmg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-date-picker/3.2.8/date-range-picker.js" integrity="sha512-SDTzsq3MW7igxEalqF5ZmjCCmB3u9EB6/+2tlh7O202zFKzrAQzH/47RPmWIePygWwRU93Odkyg5OnU45enFIw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-date-picker/3.2.8/tiny-date-picker.js" integrity="sha512-81caHXixVFIoMBwzWVOphLw5TDXsT+PVglggWRAiWdhQUaBhegldeH44KjRykOPx7l0xgL/ZPtIrKhGQgTnjjw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<table id="item_offer_table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```